# What frameworks exists for UI documentation?

Tags: documentation, style-guide, design-system

I´m working on a style guide which I want to put on the web with info, examples etc.

I know there is one API / framework called [Fractal](http://fractal.build/), but it does not have the look and feel I want. I see a lot of documentation following this pattern: https://semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar.html#/settings and it has the look and feel I want.

Does anyone know what framework / API I can use?

Comment: For my UI Design System I used http://astrum.nodividestudio.com/ .

Comment: Just be aware of the terminology that you are using since there are some differences between style guides that are published online, design frameworks and development frameworks. I can't quite tell what you are after from the question but since you seem to be after a particular look and feel, I get you are after a design system that has the structure and content that suits your needs with a similar style?

Comment: As I commented below, it's not the look and feel of the creative side of making a style guide for my website. It's the look and feel which the documentation API outputs. For example, Fractal is missing the right menu column which you can see in semantic-ui.com.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually quite a few resources on the web that you can use to help structure your UI documentation. Most of these are either published design or development frameworks like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) or collections of style guides that you can copy or clone like [Website Style Guide Resources](http://styleguides.io/).

Also, there are usually articles written about design frameworks or style guides like this [one](https://www.canva.com/learn/apple-google-starbucks-inside-the-web-design-style-guides-of-10-famous-companies/) by Canva that you can follow the links to and look at how they have created them.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I'm not looking for existing design systems or style guides. I already have a style guide in Sketch. I'm looking for a API that I can use to code / present my Style Guide.

Comment: @Steven my point was that many of these style guides are publicly available for you to 'clone' and modify as required, rather than just things that you can reference without being able to use the code.

Comment: I still think we are talking past each other :)
If I clone Bootstrap, then I have the Bootstrap library and I can use / modify those components in my web page. That´s not what I want. I want the framework that created the page that is showing the Bootstrap design guide.

Comment: @Steven I think you will find that like tools that help you build website templates, these are still going to be limiting in what they allow you to do straight out of the box and what you need to customize yourself (compared to creating one from scratch anyway). I have created many design systems in the past, and most of the time consuming work is doing the thinking behind it rather than the implementation. If you find the design system that is most similar to what you want to create, wouldn't the logical starting point be to take what is there and modify it to suit your purpose?